# Not loading the desired ViewController and View iOS development

Tags: ios, mapkit

I created a windows based application in xCode. My question is that what is the purpose of windows based application. Now, I want to load my custom controller but whenever I run the application anything inside the appname_iphone is executed. Inside my AppDelegate.m I am doing the following:

```
-(void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [_window addSubview:jogViewController.view];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

But jogViewController is never loaded. The JogBuddyAppDelegate_iPhone is always executed which loads the view.

UPDATE 1:

In the interface builder I clicked on the MainWindow_iPhone.xib and then I clicked on the App Delegate and changed the custom class to JogViewController. Now, when I run the application I get the following error:

```
2011-07-12 13:06:19.925 JogBuddy[3139:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<JogViewController 0x5a067e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key window.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you drag a view controller in in MainWindow.xib and link it to the view controller you defined in the app delegate?

Comment: @azamsharp I think you misinterpreted what Jack said.  From what I can see, he's asking if you created a separate object for you view controller and hooked it up to your app delegate's `jogViewController` outlet, not if you replaced your app delegate with a view controller.

Comment: I got it working thanks a lot! Now I will move all the code to the controller from the appdelegate file :D